# python 3 definition problem import string module

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am not well versed in python... my professor posted a piece of code that includes the following lines:

```
def formatOptions(options):
    from string import joinfields, strip, split

    options = joinfields(map(strip, split(strip(options), '\n')), ':')
    return options
```

When I run this using idle 2.7, I do not get an error message.  But when I run it using python 3, I get an error message.  Is this a difference in the two versions, or do I have a problem with the python 3 build?  This is the error message:

```
 File "ml_exercise.py", line 46, in <module> 

    formatOptions(options))

  File "ml_exercise.py", line 28, in formatOptions


    from string import joinfields, strip, split

ImportError: cannot import name 'joinfields'
```

Comment: Did you try comparing the [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) documentation? You should always read the docs.

Comment: I looked to see if joinfields is a method in both versions.  I was not able to find anything that obviously stated that, but saw that joinfields was the same as string.join().  I tried changing the joinfields, strip and split to string.join, string.strip and string.split but that didn't work

Comment: @CuriousGeorge119 those are now (well, since Python 1.6...) methods, not functions. cf my answer for the pythonic way to write your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string` functions where already mostly deprecated (in favor of the `str` class methods) in Python 1.6.0 (that is some 18 years ago). The idiomatic way to write this code is

```
options = ':'.join(part.strip() for part in options.strip().splitlines())
```

Comment: That worked!!!  Thank you so much!!!  I VERY MUCH appreciate it!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Unsung hero indeed

Comment: That was an easy one actually (the hardest part was to find out which python version introduced string methods actually - I would have swear they already existed in 1.5.2, but well, my memory is not that accurate obviously) - but thanks anyway ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`joinfields` removed from Python in version 3. Just use the string `join` function like:

```
options = ':'.join(map(strip, split(strip(options), '\n')))
```